# What is the meaning of "Re-run cmake no build system arguments"?

Tags: cmake

I have been getting the messsage

```
Re-run cmake no build system arguments
```

And various failures of my nascent CMake build system. I have also googled and found about a dozen results where that error message appears, but none of those hits tell you what the specific message means. Most of these cases are on the websites of specific projects, so the specific project maintainers just skip over hours of analysis and spit out a reason for the message, which the project user is happy to use.

I have also stumbled onto the CMake source code line which emits this text.

```
if (this->CheckBuildSystemArgument.empty()) {
  if (verbose) {
    cmSystemTools::Stdout("Re-run cmake no build system arguments\n");
  }
  return 1;
}
```

So an argument is empty. This doesn't explain anything because a minimal valid invocation of 'cmake' is

```
cmake .
```

It's not the best invocation:

```
cmake ..
```

is regarded as much better by CMake mavens, assuming that the current directory is empty and the parent has CMakeLists.txt. People who use CMake all the time will recognize that there isn't normally a 'build system argument' on the command line. If you search the cmake.org documentation there is no documentation of such concept as a "build system" or "build system argument".

The build system I am trying to bring into existence is a bit complex to faithfully summarize here. So instead I would like to learn what this message actually means and some idea of how I could make it go away. I tried minimizing my build system to fix a different problem, in fact, and I didn't even reproduce the problem. Also that minimization was in an outer layer, which is in fact a Makefile and covered an issue of controlling things with environment variables.

So, could someone tell me what "Re-run cmake no build system arguments" means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start off with some context, there is plenty of info in the CMake documentation about build systems, as this is CMake's primary function. CMake *is* a build system generator. From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#introduction-to-cmake-buildsystems), a summary of CMake's role with regard to build systems:

> A *buildsystem* describes how to build a project’s executables and libraries from its source code using a *build tool* to automate the process. For example, a buildsystem may be a `Makefile` for use with a command-line make tool or a project file for an Integrated Development Environment (IDE). In order to avoid maintaining multiple such buildsystems, a project may specify its buildsystem abstractly using files written in the CMake language. From these files CMake generates a preferred buildsystem locally for each user through a backend called a *generator*.

With that in mind, CMake tries to make things easy by checking the build system for us. This way, if we update our CMake files, we don't have to remember to re-run CMake and regenerate the build system. This "build system check" runs **by default** when invoking `cmake` from the command line. But, it will also run when you build your code (e.g. by running `make`), to verify your build system is up-to-date.

You can actually see the special pre-defined CMake target that checks your build system. For Makefile-based build systems, it will look something like this in your Makefile:

```
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -S$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

The undocumented CMake command line option `--check-build-system` followed by the `CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake` is the "build system argument" you were seeking.

This message:

```
Re-run cmake no build system arguments
```

appears when running `cmake` because CMake still internally performs a build system check. In this case, the `--check-build-system` argument is not provided so CMake always regenerates as expected. So, it is not an error message, but simply a verbose log message giving a little more information about what CMake is doing.

---

For what it's worth, this "build system check" should occur with **all** CMake build systems. For example, Visual Studio creates a `ZERO_CHECK` target which has the same behavior. It uses the `--check-stamp-list` command line option (also undocumented) instead to check to ensure your project/solution is up-to-date.

---

Another note: you can *disable* CMake's automatic build system check by switching the [`CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION.html?highlight=suppress#variable:CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION) variable to `ON`. Just place this at the bottom of your top-level CMake file:

```
set(CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION ON)
```

Of course, CMake will always regenerate when you invoke `cmake` directly. But when this variable is `ON`, the special regeneration target will be removed (`cmake_check_build_system` for Makefiles, `ZERO_CHECK` for Visual Studio, etc).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up considering this message as not a diagnostic, after adding an argument that cmake always defaults: -G "Unix Makefiles", and then moving on.

Comment: Also I really appreciate knowing where that message comes from because I don't get it very often (this may have been the first time) and I was really out in the Pampas with this build system generally. *Was*.

Comment: Well, so you'll only see this message if you run cmake verbosely. Today I came across it actually because I accidentally added `VERBOSE=1` to my cmake call rather than my make call, which worked more or less similarly, but still left differences. But I tracked it down!

--- So, it's nice to know the meaning and provenance of this message, but surely I can't be the first to point out that "Re-run cmake no build system arguments" doesn't actually grammatically parse to anything sensible. As best as I can figure out based on this answer, it should be: `No build system args: re-running cmake`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was calling:

1. `cmake -S "sourcedir" -B "builddir" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug`
2. `cmake --build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" --parallel builddir`

Then, cmake was thinking that `builddir` was an argument to `--parallel`. Looks like `--parallel` can take an optional argument, the number of threads to use, and entering an invalid value does not trigger any errors. This makes difficult to catch problems with cmake command line.

The fix is just adding `--parallel` as the last argument to cmake: `cmake --build builddir -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" --parallel`,